# Codeanywhere like online development environment

Tags: software-development, web-development

I'm interested in online development, [Codeanywhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codeanywhere) is pretty fine. However I need something free and where my projects remain "always on" (I mean terminal or PHP)

**EDIT:** It would be great if there's such an app I can host myself (web script). I tried [Codiad](http://codiad.com), it's just an IDE (that's also interesting) but it doesn't support compiling.

**EDIT2:** Here's my minimal needs

- Online development environment with Linux terminal support
- Free / trial / open source
- Must continue running after I close my browser

Other:

- Any free or open source web script capable of doing similar things I stated

Comment: Are you just asking for a free PHP hosting, or do you want something else?

Comment: Actually I'm looking for online Linux terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this one: [Gitpod](https://www.gitpod.io/)

It's open source but your projects are online only when you're logged in. You can easily test bash scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some I know of:

- Cloud9 - https://aws.amazon.com/cloud9/
- Koding - https://www.koding.com/

  - Was a full Ubuntu machine where you can run (almost) anything. Also had an online IDE.
  - Used the Free tier a while back to do work. Pricing and features have changed since then.

Comment: hi, I edited my question.